# Is SATA III 6 GB/s a bottleneck to i7 4th Gen Laptop processor

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, cpu, sata

Should I consider upgrading my Sata 2.5" inch SSD from SATA to Nvme m2 SSD.I have a 512 GB Samsung EVO 850 (I get around 450 MBps read / 350 MBps write).
Now that the new Samsung PRO 950(2.5 GBps read / 1.5 GBps write as written on a website) are coming out will it considerably reduce boot speed and increase system performance or the CPU will be the new bottleneck?

```
                                          PS:I have a 4720HQ processor.
```

Comment: The `Samsung PRO 950` only comes in a PCI-E m.2 variant.  So unless your motherboard has a PCI-E M.2 slot you wouldn't be able to use the `Samsung PRO 950` in your system.

Comment: Yes, I opened the user serviceable bay, and I will have one m2 slot left If I use a caddy and move the EVO 850 to replace DVD drive.That being said I still don't know whether my HM87 chipset will support Nvme or not.Any idea Guys ?

Comment: I very much doubt a motherboard for a 4th generation processor has a PCI-E M.2 slot.  It might have a M.2 slot but I highly suspect it is a SATA 3 M.2 slot.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/75528/Intel-DH82HM87-PCH Can you make it out from the sheet If it is possible?         It says "PCI Express Revision 2.0"

Comment: To understand where I am coming from I have a premium motherboard for a 4th generation Intel processor and I don't even have a PCI-E M.2 slot on my motherboard.  Why are you sending me documentation on the chipset, I see no evidence, you have a PCI-E M.2 slot.

Comment: You mean the PCIe m2 slot is vendor specific and varies from manufacturer to manufacturer? Bad for me, as I have a notebook I can't even upgrade the motherboard, I think.

Comment: If I meant that I would have said that.  The M.2 standard can be SATA 3 or PCI-E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once SSDs exceed 550MB/s in either direction then the SATA3 6G standard becomes a bottleneck, to overcome this you need to move to PCI-E or PCI via M.2 to use a faster bus.

*That said*, most users do not have the use case for such transfer speeds, windows won't boot that much faster and most day to day applications won't utilize 1500MB/s writes. The reason to spend the extra money on one would be write intensive databases or high traffic webservers where traditional SATA SSDs don't have the IOPS to keep up with demand.